# Running Loop Even When If Statement Fails BATCH FILE

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

This is the first batch file ive tried to make. It is supposed to be a fake log in server thing for a youtube video. **I want it to go to the ELSE statement when I enter the wrong password (in the IF statement) but even when the IF statement fails, is runs :loop and :loop2 in side of the IF.**

```
@echo off
title Classified Server Login Service
:prompt
echo Welcome to the Classified Server Login service. 
set /p pass="Enter Password: "
    IF %pass%==3arc2015 (
    echo Logging in...
    @timeout /T 3 /nobreak >NUL
    cls
    echo Login succesful!
    set /p title="Enter File Name: "
    echo Checking...
    @timeout /T 4 /nobreak >NUL
    echo File found.
    set /p dest="Enter Download Destination: "
    echo Destination set!
    @timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
    echo Beginning download...
    @timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
    :loop2
    cls
    echo Contacting Download Server.  (74.56.9.245)
    @timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
    cls
    echo Contacting Download Server.. (74.56.9.245)
    @timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
    cls
    echo Contacting Download Server...(74.56.9.245)
    @timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
    cls
echo Contacting Download Server.  (74.56.9.245)
@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
cls
echo Contacting Download Server.. (74.56.9.245)
@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
cls
echo Contacting Download Server...(74.56.9.245)
@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
:loop
set /a num=%num%+1
title Downloading %title%... %num%KB Downloaded.
echo %num%KB downloaded.
goto loop

) else (
    echo FAIL
    pause
)

set /p a="Press ENTER to close"
```

Comment: You can't use `goto` within an `if`/`else` block; instead you could move your `:loop` into a sub-routine -- see `call /?`...

Comment: I don't know what a sub-routine is, I just started leaning this. Whats call /?

Comment: Open a command prompt, type `call /?` and press enter.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it all in one batch file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good with `IF` and `()` so I proceeded as follows:
also I added 3 retry fail.

```
@echo off
setlocal
title Classified Server Login Service

set /a "_p=0"
:prompt
cls
echo Welcome to the Classified Server Login service.
set /a "_p=_p+1"
IF "%_p%"=="4" goto fail
set /p "_pass=Enter Password: " || set "_pass=NothingChosen"
IF "%_pass%" NEQ "3arc2015" goto prompt
goto logging

:fail
echo fail
endlocal
exit /b 0

:logging
echo Logging in...
@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
cls
echo Login succesful!
set /p title="Enter File Name: "
echo Checking...
@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
echo File found.
set /p dest="Enter Download Destination: "
echo Destination set!
@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
echo Beginning download...
@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL

:loop2
cls
echo Contacting Download Server.  (74.56.9.245^)
@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
cls
echo Contacting Download Server.. (74.56.9.245^)
@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
cls
echo Contacting Download Server...(74.56.9.245^)
@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL

:loop
REM title Downloading %title%... %num%KB Downloaded.
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,10) DO (
  cls
  echo %%G KB downloaded.
  @timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
)
echo download finished.
set /p a="Press ENTER to close"
endlocal
EXIT /B 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that you probably don't even remember this project of yours, but I will still *simply* fix your problem.

What is happening is that cmd does not recognize (For whatever reason), that you ended the IF statement.. What I did is enter a "IF NOT" statement.

```
@echo off
title Classified Server Login Service
:prompt
echo Welcome to the Classified Server Login service. 
set /p pass="Enter Password: "
IF %pass%==himan (
echo Logging in...
@timeout /T 3 /nobreak >NUL
cls
echo Login succesful!
set /p title="Enter File Name: "
echo Checking...
@timeout /T 4 /nobreak >NUL
echo File found.
set /p dest="Enter Download Destination: "
echo Destination set!
@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
echo Beginning download...
@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
)
IF NOT %pass%==himan CLS & Echo FAILED... Try again & goto prompt
:loop2
cls
echo Contacting Download Server.  (74.56.9.245)
@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
cls
echo Contacting Download Server.. (74.56.9.245)
@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
cls
echo Contacting Download Server...(74.56.9.245)
@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
cls
echo Contacting Download Server.  (74.56.9.245)
@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
cls
echo Contacting Download Server.. (74.56.9.245)
@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
cls
echo Contacting Download Server...(74.56.9.245)
@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
:loop
set /a num=%num%+1
title Downloading %title%... %num%KB Downloaded.
echo %num%KB downloaded.
goto loop


set /p a="Press ENTER to close"
```